# Two Software Center Icons 16.04

Tags: software-center, icons, 16.04

After upgrade to 16.04 from 15.10, I see two software center icons. One works, the other doesn't.

In the image below, the right works, the left doesn't. The left, when clicked, doesn't do anything, except the icon appearing in the launcher, and breathing like it's gonna open, but doesn't

How do I get rid of the left one if it doesn't work?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Remove the old version after upgrade

When you *upgrade* from previous Ubuntu versions, the "old" Software-center is not removed it seems. Since it is replaced by the new Software-center, you can remove it by running the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove software-center
```

This will *not* remove the new software-center, since it has a different package name.

If the icon still is there:

#### Most likely

Software Center was update to the latest version for 16.04, but the old `.desktop` file was left behind.

*What to do if this is the case*

- Browse in nautilus to `/usr/share/applications`
- Drag either one of the `.desktop` files with "software" in its name on to the launcher and try to start it from there. If it launches succesfully, that's obviously the one to keep.

  ***Note***: the *file* name of the new `.desktop` file is `org.gnome.Software.desktop`, showing "Software" in `nautilus`, while the old one was named `ubuntu-software-center.desktop`, showing "Ubuntu Software Center" in `nautilus`.
- Test the other one to test similarly until you find the outdated one

#### Another option

is that for some reason, in the past you (or software you used) made a local copy of the global `.desktop` file. If the solution below gives no result, look in `~/.local/share/applications` for a file `ubuntu-software-center.desktop` and remove it, log out and back in.

Comment: found the logo in the `/usr/share/applications`. Deleted it, and gone. Thanks

Comment: @Rexford perfect! glad it works :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm if that an upgraded version the old software center is most likely still there and can be used.

Comment: @Videonauth I guess not, the old software center was removed, but its .desktop file was left behind. Also the command changed from `/usr/bin/software-center` to `gnome-software`.

Comment: Then have a look [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SiMms.jpg) I'm running on an upgraded 16.04

Comment: @JacobVlijm I have a similar case, but in my case both software centers are opening. I have also upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04. Will your answer help me as well?