# System Settings in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, settings, system-settings, gnome-control-center

[image: three system settings]

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. After installing gnome-control-center and online-accounts, there are three settings in dashboard. Anyone helps me to fix it, please!

Comment: i'm seeing the same thing, i've also got two different Software Centers

Comment: I found the answer for you, Nick: [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/763016/two-software-center-icons-16-04)

Comment: Thnx Khoa! Taking a look now